# Running a function before async ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm trying to run a function before async ajax request. However function is running after async request gets the respond.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

```
block();

ajaxRequest= $.ajax({
    url: siteURL+'includes/ajax/action.php',
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: {productID : productID},
    dataType: "json"
});
ajaxRequest.done(function(data) {
            block(true);
            if (data === false) {
                alerts('error title','error info here', 'error', 200);
                return false;
            }
});
ajaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {block(true); alerts('error title','error info','error');});
confirm();
```

I run more functions after these codes. However as I stated before, `block();` function is waiting till async ajax request is getting response.

If I don't run asynchronous, then I get `block()` and `confirm()` functions running at the same time so `return false;` losing all the meaning.

P.S. I run these codes when a form is submitted so if async request is failed I don't want it to run any other code after it. However when it is asynchronously running `block()` is waiting till response is returned.

Comment: Call the function *before* you call the ajax request by putting the line that calls the function above the line that executes the ajax request.

Comment: well maybe that wasn't obvious but I already run the function before.

Comment: Well, you didnt' post any code, so it's just guessing. ;-)

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to accomplish? The original `block()` is running before the request is sent.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus If `block()` is performing a graphical or dom change, it may not appear to happen before the ajax request due to `async:false` stopping browser rendering.

Comment: @KevinB That's why I'm asking for clarification. ;p

Comment: `block()` is just adding overlay with the text 'please wait...' when it is `block(true)`, it is removing the overlay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is `async:false`. Your request is NOT an async request, it is a sync request. It blocks javascript code and browser rendering from happening while the request is being processed. With your current setup, there should be no harm in removing `async: false,` thus making it async.

```
block();

ajaxRequest= $.ajax({
    url: siteURL+'includes/ajax/action.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {productID : productID},
    dataType: "json"
});
ajaxRequest.done(function(data) {
            block(true);
            if (data === false) {
                alerts('error title','error info here', 'error', 200);
                return false;
            }
});
ajaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {block(true); alerts('error title','error info','error');});
ajaxRequest.always(confirm);
```

Comment: @Revenant This solution should work perfectly. If for some unknown reason, it doesn't you may want to consider using the 'beforeSend' callback built into the jQuery .ajax functionality.

Comment: `beforeSend` might be really helpful. However it will push me to add over 300 lines of codes to in `beforeSend`. The same goes to `confirm()` and codes after that. I believe there is no easy way around this. Maybe I should say; I just want `block()` to run after that wait for a response from ajax request and then proceed (if ajax request is not returning false).

Comment: @Revenant did you see the sample code i just added? it makes confirm run after the async request.

Comment: Yes Kevin B, thank you for your help. It will just require massive editing to my .js file. I just wanted to make things short by adding `block();` and `confirm();`. However there are hundreds of lines of codes before and after that ajax request.